# Xcode 12 very slow to launch simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, simulator

Someone could help me ?

I have a problem with Xcode 12.4, the application takes more than 5 minutes to launch the app and stay blocked building the app.

It's not a problem with my application because i have tried with the new app and the problem still be the same.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Run once and wait for the `Simulator` home screen to load. After loaded, re-run the app from `Xcode`. ‍♂️

### Explanation

I am not sure if this will actually fix the issue, but usually, I fully open the `Simulator.app` for that device and wait for the Home screen to load before running the app. I think `Springboard (Xcode)` waits to get a handshake response when the device has fully launched and then attaches the process. This handshake was a bottleneck for me.

### Other potential causes

1. Disable `Springboard` injection apps like `Sherlock.app`.
2. Reduce the number of simulators open at a given time to increase available RAM.
3. Reduce the number of open apps so that `Xcode` gets more CPU time to run.
4. Disable `Debug executable` setting (or other runtime settings) in `Edit Scheme` in Xcode to check if the Xcode debugger is faulty (workaround).
5. Try a newer `Mac` (2017 or later, but ideally an M1) as they have more RAM and are faster.
6. Reduce App `Bundle` size - smaller `Asset Catalog`s, `Preview Content` folders, fewer third-party libraries, and no duplicate source files (including the iCloud Desktop/Document Sync `zombie files` bug).
7. Disable `iCloud Desktop and Documents Folder syncing`. Or at least wait till the whole laptop has been synced. The `bird` daemons et al. are quite intensive.

Comment: Author of SimGenie here - SG does not inject any code for the simulator, it does all its work via the command line `simctl` tool that Apple provides.

Comment: Sherlock.app definitely does work with Springboard (according to their NSLondon talk), so I assumed SG did as well. I've corrected the answer now